# How to Export Ag-Grid to PDF Format in Angular 2?

Tags: angular, ag-grid

I'm working on AG-GRID in Angular 2. I have found that there is an option only to export the grid into Excel.

How can I export the grid into PDF?

Answer (score 4):

Exporting to pdf whilst keeping the styling is a pretty tricky task and there are a few options out there to do what you desire.

1. [html2pdf](https://github.com/eKoopmans/html2pdf): This converts the html to canvas then from canvas to an image and then from image to pdf. The problem is that this implementation tends to produce a low resolution image.
2. [jsPdf](https://github.com/MrRio/jsPDF): This library is a js implementation and therefore does not include the page styling. Styles have to be added separately using the `jsPdf` and it is a bit limited so recreating the quite complex design generated by `AG_GRID` would require a lot of work.
3. [phantomjs](http://phantomjs.org/screen-capture.html): This is a headless bowser which Api provides screen capture capability. [rastersize](https://github.com/ariya/phantomjs/blob/master/examples/rasterize.js) is an example of the implementation, this can be integrated into an app by creating a que for calls to phantomjs.

Answer (score 1):

You can print the grid data. Chrome gives you an option to save it as pdf. But, you might have other html elements in the page, which you probably don't want to be a part of the PDF (or, print). So:

1. Render the grid in a separate page (You can transfer the grid state
   object to a separate component to render exactly the same grid view
   (Sort, filter etc).
2. Call the grid function `api.setDomLayout('print');`
3. Call `window.print()`.
4. Redirect him back to the previous page.

I have written an example code (Take it as an example only, tweak as per needs):
https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ag-grid-pdf

You can play with the width to fill the page.

Comment: ,good code you have write, i need code for java script instead of type script,Please

Comment: it will print only the visible area of the page and grid. if grid has scroll bar and data out of sight it wont include in the pdf print. thanks

Answer (score 0):

pdfMake integrates well with ag-Grid. You just have to create a 2D array containing the values in all column headers and rows.

```js
function getColumnsToExport() {
    let columnsToExport = [];

    agGridColumnApi.getAllDisplayedColumns().forEach(col => {
      let pdfExportOptions = getPdfExportOptions(col.getColId());
      if (pdfExportOptions && pdfExportOptions.skipColumn) {
        return;
      }
      let headerCell = createHeaderCell(col);
      columnsToExport.push(headerCell);
    });

    return columnsToExport;
  }

  function getRowsToExport(columnsToExport) {
    let rowsToExport = [];

    agGridApi.forEachNodeAfterFilterAndSort(node => {
      if (PDF_SELECTED_ROWS_ONLY && !node.isSelected()) {
        return;
      }
      let rowToExport = columnsToExport.map(({ colId }) => {
        let cellValue = agGridApi.getValue(colId, node);
        let tableCell = createTableCell(cellValue, colId);
        return tableCell;
      });
      rowsToExport.push(rowToExport);
    });

    return rowsToExport;
  }
```

You can even define styling options so that the exported table looks just like ag-Grid:

```js
PDF_HEADER_COLOR = "#f8f8f8";
PDF_INNER_BORDER_COLOR = "#dde2eb";
PDF_OUTER_BORDER_COLOR = "#babfc7";
PDF_HEADER_HEIGHT = 25;
PDF_ROW_HEIGHT = 15;
PDF_ODD_BKG_COLOR = "#fcfcfc";
PDF_EVEN_BKG_COLOR = "#ffffff";

const heights = rowIndex =>
      rowIndex < headerRows ? PDF_HEADER_HEIGHT : PDF_ROW_HEIGHT;

    const fillColor = (rowIndex, node, columnIndex) => {
      if (rowIndex < node.table.headerRows) {
        return PDF_HEADER_COLOR;
      }
      return rowIndex % 2 === 0 ? PDF_ODD_BKG_COLOR : PDF_EVEN_BKG_COLOR;
    };

    const hLineWidth = (i, node) =>
      i === 0 || i === node.table.body.length ? 1 : 1;

    const vLineWidth = (i, node) =>
      i === 0 || i === node.table.widths.length ? 1 : 0;

    const hLineColor = (i, node) =>
      i === 0 || i === node.table.body.length
        ? PDF_OUTER_BORDER_COLOR
        : PDF_INNER_BORDER_COLOR;

    const vLineColor = (i, node) =>
      i === 0 || i === node.table.widths.length
        ? PDF_OUTER_BORDER_COLOR
        : PDF_INNER_BORDER_COLOR;
```

See the example below in angular:

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ag-grid-pdf-make?file=src%2Findex.html