# How to export .PDF version of `ag-grid` with fixed header?

Tags: javascript, angular, ag-grid, jspdf, html2canvas

I need to export `Ag-Grid` to `PDF`. To do this I became able to convert `ag-grid` `div` to `canvas` (html2canvas) `img`. So, converting `img` to `PDF` (jsPdf) works fine.

[image]

But since I have pinned header on Grid,it only converts the visible part of grid not all rows in grid.
To do this I tried something like below but didn't work

```js
downloadAsPdf() {
    let doc = new jsPDF();
    html2canvas(this.agGrid["_nativeElement"]).then(canvas => {
        var imgWidth = 210;
        var pageHeight = 295;
        var imgHeight = canvas.height * imgWidth / canvas.width;
        var position = 0;
        var heightLeft = imgHeight;
        let imageData = getBase64Image(canvas);
        doc.addImage(imageData, "PNG", 0, position, imgWidth, imgHeight);
        heightLeft -= pageHeight;
        while (heightLeft >= 0) {
            position = heightLeft - imgHeight;
            doc.addPage();
            doc.addImage(imageData, 'PNG', 0, position, imgWidth, imgHeight);
            heightLeft -= pageHeight;
        }
        doc.save("example.pdf");
    });
}

function getBase64Image(img) {
    var canvas = document.createElement("canvas");
    canvas.width = img.width;
    canvas.height = img.height;
    var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
    ctx.drawImage(img, 0, 0);
    var dataURL = canvas.toDataURL("image/png");
    return dataURL;
}
```

I also tried to send second parameter to html2Canvas like below but didnt work either

```
    {scrollY: -window.scrollY}
{
        scrollX: 0,
        scrollY: 0
      }
```

Stackblitz link:
https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-grid-dynamic-height-snfadt?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts

Comment: Have you tried this? https://stackoverflow.com/a/61487781/9449426

Comment: This opens print page not download directly

Answer (score 0):

pdfMake includes the header row of a table on every page by default.

See the example below:

https://stackblitz.com/edit/js-ag-grid-pdf-make?file=index.js

To create the exported table you need to create a 2D array containing all columns and rows to be exported. This can be done with the ag-Grid API which allows you to iterate over all columns and rows with the methods `columnApi.getAllDisplayedColumns()` and `gridApi.forEachNode`.